# How to find the last password changed user in Linux

Tags: linux, password-management

I want to find the recent username whose password has been changed. Is there any way to get the username?

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of users, If you are using LDAP for user authentication, `getent` will display all Linux users from both `/etc/passwd` file and LDAP database the 1000 to 60000 are for non system users i.e. normal users, then pipe users and extract and use the first field to get just the user name and then use the `chage` command is used to return the user password expiry information

```
for user in $(getent passwd {1000..60000} | awk -F: '{ print $1}'); do echo "$user" && chage -l $user ; done
```